# How to install the package of image in octave gnu?

Tags: nancy

I have tried installing a package in `Octave` using this command:

```
pkg install image-2.12.0.tar
```

But I received the following error:

> error: pkg: failed to read package 'image-2.12.0.tar': Couldn't
>   resolve host name error: called from pkg at line 433 column 17

Does somebody know what that means?

Answer (score 4):

There are two options.

If you want to install the latest version of image from octave forage.

```
pkg install -forge image
```

Note it is just the name of the package, the -forge option tells it to download from octave forge.

If you have already downloaded the package (and it is in current directory) then

```
pkg install image-2.12.0.tar.gz
```

Note it is the full file name of package save the file is on your hard drive.